# Find common third on large data set

Tags: r, large-data

I have a large dataframe like

```
df <- data.frame(group= c("a","a","b","b","b","c"),
             person = c("Tom","Jerry","Tom","Anna","Sam","Nic"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df
    group person
1     a    Tom
2     a  Jerry
3     b    Tom
4     b   Anna
5     b    Sam
6     c    Nic
```

and would like to get as a result

```
df.output
  pers1 pers2 person_in_common
1  Anna Jerry              Tom
2 Jerry   Sam              Tom
3   Sam   Tom             Anna
4  Anna   Tom              Sam
6  Anna   Sam              Tom
```

The result dataframe gives basically a table with all pairs of persons who have another person in common. I found a way to do it in SQL but it takes an awfully long time so I wonder if there is a efficient way to do it in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one using `igraph` package. The basic idea is to create a graph and then extract two adjacent nodes for each node.

```
library(igraph)
X1 = split(df$person, df$group)
X2 = X1[lengths(X1) >= 2]
dat = data.frame(do.call(rbind, unlist(lapply(X2, function(x)
            combn(x, 2, sort, FALSE)), recursive = FALSE)))
g = graph.data.frame(dat, directed = FALSE)
mydf = data.frame(as.matrix(get.adjacency(g)))
mydf = mydf[colSums(mydf) > 1]
ANS = sapply(mydf, function(x) t(combn(row.names(mydf)[which(x == 1)], 2)))
do.call(rbind, lapply(names(ANS), function(nm) data.frame(ANS[[nm]], nm)))
#     X1   X2   nm
#1   Sam  Tom Anna
#2  Anna  Tom  Sam
#3 Jerry Anna  Tom
#4 Jerry  Sam  Tom
#5  Anna  Sam  Tom
```

OR

```
mynames = unique(do.call(c, X2))
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(mynames, function(x){
            L = V(g)$name[unlist(adjacent_vertices(graph = g, v = x))]
            if(length(L) >= 2){
                setNames(data.frame(t(combn(L, 2)), x), c("P1", "P2", "P3"))
            }else{
                setNames(data.frame(NA, NA, x), c("P1", "P2", "P3"))
            }
        }))
#     P1   P2    P3
#1 Jerry Anna   Tom
#2 Jerry  Sam   Tom
#3  Anna  Sam   Tom
#4  <NA> <NA> Jerry
#5   Sam  Tom  Anna
#6  Anna  Tom   Sam
```

Comment: It works well for a normal sized data set but I run into memory issues with my actual data when I try to set up `mydf` adjacency matrix (`g` is almost 1gb in size).

Comment: I tried that but I guess the matrix is just too large. Was also mucking around with sparse matrix but couldn’t figure it out. I’ll try some more and then accept your answer as it solves the general problem.

Comment: It is not crashing with the 2nd version @d.b but still running. I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: Was running for three days @d.b so I had to stop it. Probably have to split it up somehow