# optimizing solution to find common third on large data set

Tags: r, optimization, bigdata

This is a follow up question to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47557369/find-common-third-on-large-data-set). I run into a problem to find a memory efficient solution to find a common third for my large data set (3.5 million groups and 6.2 million persons)

The proposed solution using the `igraph` package works fast for a normal sized data sets unfortunately runs into memory issues by creating a large matrix for bigger data sets. Similar issue comes up with my own solution using concatenated inner joins where the third inner join inflates the dataframe so my pc runs out of memory (16gb).

```
    df.output <-   inner_join(df,df, by='group' ) %>% 
      inner_join(.,df, by=c('person.y'='person')) %>%
      inner_join(.,df, by=c('group.y'='group')) %>% 
      rename(person_in_common='person.y', pers1='person.x',pers2='person') %>% 
      select(pers1,pers2,person_in_common) %>% 
      filter(pers1!=pers2) %>% 
      distinct() %>% 
      filter(person_in_common!=pers1 & person_in_common!=pers2)

    df.output[-3] <- t(apply(df.output[-3], 1, 
                             FUN=function(x) sort(x, decreasing=FALSE)))

    df.output <- unique(df.output)
```

Small data set example and expected output

```
df <- data.frame(group= c("a","a","b","b","b","c"),
             person = c("Tom","Jerry","Tom","Anna","Sam","Nic"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df
    group person
1     a    Tom
2     a  Jerry
3     b    Tom
4     b   Anna
5     b    Sam
6     c    Nic
```

and expected result

```
df.output
  pers1 pers2 person_in_common
1  Anna Jerry              Tom
2 Jerry   Sam              Tom
3   Sam   Tom             Anna
4  Anna   Tom              Sam
6  Anna   Sam              Tom
```

I unfortunately don't have access to a machine with more ram and are also not really experienced with cloud computing, so I hope to make it work on my local pc. I would appreciate input how to optimize any of the solutions or an advise how to tackle the problem otherwise.

**Edit 1**

A dataframe which reflects my actual data size.

```
set.seed(33)

Data <- data.frame(group = sample(1:3700000, 14000000, replace=TRUE),
                   person = sample(1:6800000, 14000000,replace = TRUE))
```

**Edit 2**

My real data is a bit more complex in terms of larger groups and more persons per group as the example data. Consequently it gets more memory intense. I could not figure out how to simulate this kind of structure so following the real data for download:

[Full person-group data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1846akDN0RrtmEzfA2y9fSzfwL_V6d-6o/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't understand how you choose the person in common.

Comment: can you give code that creates example data of the size you want to process?

Comment: can you even crater the first join (`inner_join(df,df, by='group')`)?

Comment: @minem, sorry for late reply. I can run the first and second join, it crashes with the third. I’ll set up a test dataframe with the actual dimensions of my real data ASAP

Comment: @F.Privé I am not sure how to explain it more clearly than with the output example. Basically you can have a common third within a group when you have at least three persons and cross groups when you two persons share a third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I managed to run this on your test data (I have 16 GB of RAM), but if you run this on your small example then you would see that it does not give the same results.  I did not get why, but maybe you could hep me with that. So I will try to explain every step:

```
myFun <- function(dt) {
  require(data.table)
  # change the data do data.table:
  setDT(dt)
  # set key/order the data by group and person:
  setkey(dt, group, person)
  # I copy the initial data and change the name of soon to be merged column name to "p2"
  # which represents person2
  dta <- copy(dt)
  setnames(dta, "person", "p2")
  # the first merge using data.table:
  dt1 <- dt[dta, on = "group", allow.cartesian = TRUE, nomatch = 0]
  # now we remove rows where persons are the same:
  dt1 <- dt1[person != p2] # remove equal persons
  # and also we need to remove rows where person1 and person2 are the same,
  # just in different order , example:
  # 2:     a    Tom    Jerry
  # 3:     a  Jerry      Tom
  # is the same, if I get it right then you did this using apply in the end of code,
  # but it would be much better if we could reduce data now
  # also my approach will be much faster (we take pairwise min word to 2 column
  # and max to the last):
  l1 <- pmin(dt1[[2]], dt1[[3]])
  l2 <- pmax(dt1[[2]], dt1[[3]])
  set(dt1, j = 2L, value = l1)
  set(dt1, j = 3L, value = l2)
  # now lets clear memory and take unique rows of dt1:
  rm(l1, l2, dt)
  dt1 <- unique(dt1)
  gc()
  # change name for group column:
  setnames(dta, "group", "g2")
  # second merge:
  dt2 <- dt1[dta, on = "p2", allow.cartesian = TRUE, nomatch = 0]
  rm(dt1)
  gc()
  setnames(dta, "p2", "p3")
  dt3 <- dt2[dta, on = "g2", allow.cartesian = TRUE, nomatch = 0] # third merge
  rm(dt2)
  gc()
  dt3 <- dt3[p3 != p2 & p3 != person] # removing equal persons
  gc()
  dt3 <- dt3[, .(person, p2, p3)]
  gc()
  return(dt3[])
}
```

On Small data set example:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("a","a","b","b","b","c"),
                 person = c("Tom","Jerry","Tom","Anna","Sam","Nic"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
myFun(df)
#    person  p2    p3
# 1:   Anna Tom Jerry
# 2:    Sam Tom Jerry
# 3:  Jerry Tom  Anna
# 4:    Sam Tom  Anna
# 5:  Jerry Tom   Sam
# 6:   Anna Tom   Sam
# 7:   Anna Sam   Tom
```

Something similar to your result but not quite the same

Now with larger data:

```
set.seed(33)
N <- 10e6
dt <- data.frame(group = sample(3.7e6, N, replace = TRUE),
                 person = sample(6.8e6, N, replace = TRUE))
system.time(results <- myFun(dt)) # 13.22 sek

rm(results)
gc()
```

And:

```
set.seed(33)
N <- 14e6
dt <- data.frame(group = sample(3.7e6, N, replace = TRUE),
                 person = sample(6.8e6, N, replace = TRUE))
system.time(results <- myFun(dt)) # around 40 sek, but RAM does get used to max
```

### Update:

Maybe you can try this splitting aproch, lets say with `nparts` 6-10?:

```
myFunNew3 <- function(dt, nparts = 2) {
  require(data.table)
  setDT(dt)
  setkey(dt, group, person)
  dta <- copy(dt)

  # split into N parts
  splits <- rep(1:nparts, each = ceiling(dt[, .N]/nparts))
  set(dt, j = "splits", value = splits)
  dtl <- split(dt, by = "splits", keep.by = F)
  set(dt, j = "splits", value = NULL)
  rm(splits)
  gc()

  i = 1
  for (i in seq_along(dtl)) {
    X <- copy(dtl[[i]])
    setnames(dta, c("group", "person"))
    X <- X[dta, on = "group", allow.cartesian = TRUE, nomatch = 0]
    X <- X[person != i.person]
    gc()
    X <- X[dta, on = "person", allow.cartesian = TRUE, nomatch = 0]
    gc()
    setnames(dta, "group", "i.group")
    X <- X[dta, on = "i.group", allow.cartesian = TRUE, nomatch = 0] 
    gc()
    setnames(X, "i.person.1", "pers2")
    setnames(X, "i.person", "pers1" )
    setnames(X, "person", "person_in_common" )
    X <- X[, .(pers1, pers2, person_in_common)]
    gc()
    X <- X[pers1 != pers2 & person_in_common != pers1 & person_in_common != pers2]
    gc()
    name1 <- "pers1"
    name2 <- "pers2"
    l1 <- pmin(X[[name1]], X[[name2]])
    l2 <- pmax(X[[name1]], X[[name2]])
    set(X, j = name1, value = l1)
    set(X, j = name2, value = l2)
    rm(l1, l2)
    gc()
    X <- unique(X)
    gc()
    if (i > 1) {
      X1 <- rbindlist(list(X1, X), use.names = T, fill = T)
      X1 <- unique(X1)
      rm(X)
      gc()
    } else {
      X1 <- copy(X)
    }
    dtl[[i]] <- 0L
    gc()
  }
  rm(dta, dtl)
  gc()
  setkey(X1, pers1, pers2, person_in_common)
  X1[]
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! I will look into it but might take a day

Comment: I proposed some minor edits @minem on your code to get the desired output. However my large data example seems not fully representative of my real data. I did some digging and found that in my data I have larger groups (more persons per group) + more persons in multiple groups than in the example data. Hence the final `dt` gets much bigger. As I don't know how to produce this particular characteristics, I'll upload the full data.

Comment: @user6617454 updated the answer, maybe this function fill do the trick

Comment: thanks @minem, sorry took me a while to check it. It runs through with the proposed split version. Really appreciate your work!